# What's the wrong with this C Code?

Tags: c, header, struct

I've written a sample program about structs. I wrote 3 source file and a 1 header file. This is the complete source of the program:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fish.h"

/*
struct fish
{
    const char *name;
    const char *species;
    int teeth;
    int age;
};
*/

/*
void catalog(struct fish f)
{
    printf("%s is a %s with %i teeth. He is %i.",
           f.name, f.species, f.teeth, f.age);
}


void label(struct fish f)
{
    printf("Name: %s\n", f.name);
    printf("Species: %s\n", f.species);
    printf("Teeth: %i\n", f.teeth);
    printf("Age: %i\n", f.age);
}
*/

int main()
{
    struct fish snappy = {"Snappy", "Piranha", 69, 4};
    catalog(snappy);
    label(snappy);

    return 0;
}
```

label.c:

```
#include "fish.h"

void label(struct fish f)
{
    printf("Name: %s\n", f.name);
    printf("Species: %s\n", f.species);
    printf("Teeth: %i\n", f.teeth);
    printf("Age: %i\n", f.age);
}
```

catalog.c:

```
#include "fish.h"

void catalog(struct fish f)
{
    printf("%s is a %s with %i teeth. He is %i.",
           f.name, f.species, f.teeth, f.age);
}
```

I also wrote a makefile:

```
fish.o: main.c label.c catalog.c fish.h
    gcc -c main.c label.c catalog.c
fish: fish.o
    gcc fish.o -o fish
```

I compile the program in cmd:

```
make fish
```

It says:

```
gcc -c main.c label.c catalog.c
label.c: In function 'label':
label.c:5:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'    [enabled by default]
catalog.c: In function 'catalog':
catalog.c:5:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default]
cc   fish.o   -o fish
cc.exe: error: fish.o: No such file or directory
cc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [fish] Error 1
```

If I remove the comments in the main.c and compile only it, It works, But when I broke into small pieces as mentioned above it doesn't work.

What's the wrong?

Comment: The compilation warnings are fixed by including `#include <stdio.h>` in the files that use `printf()`.  Don't bother to struggle with alternatives; just include the standard header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This linking rule:

```
fish: fish.o
    gcc fish.o -o fish
```

is appropriate for building a program `fish` from a single object file `fish.o` (which is presumably compiled from `fish.c`).

You need a different rule:

```
OBJECTS = main.o label.o catalog.o

fish: ${OBJECTS}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${OBJECTS}
```

You can add `${CFLAGS}` and `${LDFLAGS}` and `${LDLIBS}` (or `${LDLIBES}`) to the link line as appropriate if you want to, but for simple programs, what I showed suffices.

You don't have to tell `make` how to convert `main.c` into `main.o`; it knows that already.  It will use a rule such as:

```
%.o: %.c
    ${CC} -c ${CFLAGS} $<
```

to create the `.o` file from the matching `.c` file.  (This is the GNU Make notation; POSIX `make` and other classic versions of `make` use an alternative but loosely equivalent notation `.c.o:` in place of `%.o: %.c`.)

If you don't mind compiling all the sources each time, you can use a similar rule:

```
SOURCES = main.c label.c catalog.c

fish: ${OBJECTS}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ ${SOURCES}
```

This time, `${CFLAGS}` is practically mandatory (though you'd just about get away without it in your bare-bones sample program).

---

Note that `make` is fussy; the command lines such as the `${CC}` lines must start with a <kbd>TAB</kbd>; blanks will not do.

Comment: it says: makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: Ensure <TAB>${CC} -o $@ ${OBJECTS}. Do not use space.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to compile all of the *.c* files together so that you can use your functions defined in *label.c* and *catalog.c* in *main.c*.

You can do this with one step using gcc:

```
gcc main.c label.c catalog.c -o fish
```

This will compile each individual source file and produce [*object* files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file), which will be linked together to produce your executable. The errors that you're seeing occur during the link phase, when gcc is trying to find the `catalog` and `label` functions.

Answer (score 3):

`gcc main.c -o fish` only compiles `main.c`. `main.c` does not know about `label.c`. It only knows that it has to call some function called "label", which is defined elsewhere. Then, the linker looks at all of the generated object files, and 'links' them into a single executable:

```
gcc main.c -c
gcc label.c -c
gcc catalog.c -c
ld main.o label.o catalog.o -o fish
```

This is the explicit version of

```
gcc main.c label.c catalog.c -o fish
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `ld` raw to link a C program; use `gcc` so it provides the correct start-up code (classically, something like `crt0.o`) and specifies the C library automatically.